# Removing cabinet baseboard facing

Tags: cabinets

We have water damage to the baseboard of our new cabinets. The baseboard appears to just be cardboard glued to an actual piece of wood. I have a piece of wood I am going to use to replace the cardboard baseboard but wondering what's the best way of removing the rest of the cardboard baseboard, from the wood baseboard, and glue.

[image: baseboard damage 1][image: baseboard damage 2]

Answer (score 1):

Those are Masonite laminated toe kick panels.

They are tacked and possibly glued to various points at the front of the cabinets.

To get them off use a hammer or maybe even a screwdriver to punch a hole starting near the center of one of the cabinets. Then get your fingers or the claw of the hammer in the hole and pull. They should come off in fairly long strips.  Then you have to clean up the nails or glue from the bases where the were anchored.

This will help you examine under the cabinets to see if there is any other damage.

Installation of the new kicks is self explanatory.

Comment: I have had cabinets where the toe kicks were clipped on to the cabinet legs with spring clips. You would probably know if this was the case, and/or you'll discover it quickly as you follow the advice in this answer.  But this answer is probably right.    If removing it is very hard going, you could consider just nailing new toe kicks onto the old ones.  If you use white composite boards 1/4 inch thick or composite siding this won't happen again.

Comment: It looks like there's a gap under the toe kick; if you can slip a large pick (or similar) underneath you might be able to just pull the end of the kick off next to the dishwasher, then just keep pulling to the left.